# RoR burke's zeus gem gives exit status 1 when using Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ubuntu, zeus

The Zeus gem https://github.com/burke/zeus works as expected on MacOSX, however, on a Linux box it exhibits the issues described (and unresolved) here: https://github.com/burke/zeus/issues/237

Using:

- Rbenv with ruby 1.9.3-p327-perf
- Ubuntu 13.04
- golang version 2:1.0.2-2 (according to "dpkg -l")
- Tried several zeus releases

---

### Problem

Terminal: "zeus start" gives "exit status 1" briefly, then the colourful terminal interface shifts down one line and it hangs, all lines "waiting" (coloured yellow).

---

### Troubleshooting so far

Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install golang
```

(On MacOSX it was "brew install go")

```
gem install zeus -v 0.13.3.rc2 --pre
```

(Have also tried "gem install zeus -v 0.13.3.rc2" and "gem install zeus" with a gem uninstall and recreation of initialisation files zeus.json and custom_plan.rb each time)

```
gem list
```

(One version of Zeus installed)

```
bundle show
```

(Zeus not bundled, as expected)

```
zeus init
```

(Also tried alternatively removing zeus.json and custom_plan.rb)

---

### Update

Also not working on MacOSX on colleague's machine:

```
> sudo brew install go
Warning: go-1.0.3 already installed

> gem list
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
method_source (0.8.1)
zeus (0.13.3)

> rbenv version
1.9.3-p327-perf
```

### Update2

Ok so I have ssh access to a Linux box (Ubuntu) which has got Zeus working on it with the same codebase. What diagnostics can I use to determine/compare what it has different to my local machine? I'm looking into dpkg --get-selections for now

### Update3

```
gem list
```

was showing the installed json version (1.5.4).

```
bundle show
```

was showing the installed json version (1.7.7).

An update on the issue here https://github.com/burke/zeus/issues/237 suggests that json version could be the problem; given that zeus is installed with the ruby version and not with the gemfile (it shows under gem list) I ran:

```
gem install json --version 1.7.7
gem uninstall json --version 1.5.4
rm zeus.json
rm custom_plan.rb
zeus init
zeus start
```

However this does not fix the problem for me, and on the mac where it is failing, Json 1.7.7 is installed.

Comment: Don't have the rep to create the "Ubuntu-13.04" tag =p

Comment: Hey this is a really useful post! It seems familiar... oh wait its mine =( How did you fix it, past self???

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had been having this same issue, and none of the troubleshooting steps [listed for this issue](https://github.com/burke/zeus/issues/237) were successful in resolving it for me.

After much hair-pulling and facedesking, I managed to get Zeus working by the following steps:

1. Remove ALL mentions of `zeus` from your Gemfile.
2. **Run `bundle clean --force` to remove ALL unused versions of ALL gems from your system.** This seems to be the important part of the fix -- zeus does NOT like finding multiple versions of gems hanging around, even if they're not in use.
3. Run `gem uninstall zeus` and remove ALL installed versions of zeus.
4. Run `gem install zeus` to get only the latest version (in my case, this was 0.15.1).
5. Run `bundle install` to make sure that all necessary gems are installed.

After this I was able to boot zeus with no issues, for the first time in a week.

Comment: For me, zeus failed only under the debugger. Your step 2 addressed the issue for me (Mac 10.9.3, ruby 1.9.3). Thanks!

Comment: All I needed to do was to remove zeus from my Gemfile.  Then I was able to boot it up.

Answer (score 1):

Based on https://github.com/burke/zeus/issues/237#issuecomment-22081635, I removed the old method_source gem by:

```
gem uninstall --all --force method_source
gem install method_source
```

And that worked.

Comment: didn’t fix it for me.. and neither did any of the other suggestions in the discussion of [issue 237](http://github.com/burke/zeus/issues/237)

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was removing zeus from my gemfile. I had, the day before, installed zeus via `gem install zeus`, but forgot to remove from my project's gemfile.  Maybe check to make sure there's only one installed version of zeus available when running `zeus start`